# How to fix the error? Laravel PDF Generate error

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

Declaration of Mpdf\Mpdf::setLogger(Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) must be compatible with Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface::setLogger(Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger): void

I tried to generate pdf file but I got this error

Comment: Most error messages have a file name and line number in them, referring to the place where the error occurs. Is the error reported in code you created? If so what does that code look like?